# Geometric Distribution and Bayesian Posterior

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, bayesian, bayes-theorem

I want to design a model, in which the player updates her belief (with Bayes rule) on the intensity (equivalently the expected arrival time) of a geometric distribution observing some sort of signal. I am looking for a tractable model, or a source to study.